# Grand Jury and criminal procedure

Tags: comparative-law

In the US, would you consider hearings before a Grand Jury part of the criminal procedure/process?

I would say it is not, because it happens before indictment, and I assume that there is not a criminal process if there is not a defendant. If so, how would you qualify it?

EDIT:  do I confuse process and trial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The criminal justice process begins when a crime is committed and ends when corrections are presented to the individuals involved. Everything that happens in the courts up to sentencing is all part of the criminal justice process. [According to the FBI](https://www.fbi.gov/stats-services/victim_assistance/a-brief-description-of-the-federal-criminal-justice-process), pretrial hearings in front of a grand jury are, in fact, part of the criminal process. Grand Juries are not always used; however, it is important to know they are not part of determining guilt or punishment.

The grand jury has quite an important role in the criminal process: prosecutors will usually work with a grand jury to decide whether to [***bring criminal charges or an indictment against a potential defendant***](http://criminal.findlaw.com/criminal-procedure/how-does-a-grand-jury-work.html) -- usually reserved for serious felonies. In summary, a Grand Jury will determine if there is enough evidence to convict an individual for a crime.

To abstractly respond to your question, Grand Jury hearings are in fact part of the criminal justice procedure. Although everyone will surely have their own opinion on the matter, just know that if it is part of the process in furthering a court case, then it is part of the criminal justice process.

Comment: _criminal  process begins when a crime is committed_, even if the crime goes unnoticed? what about an investigation which goes nowhere? Also, _Everything that happens in the courts_ seems to imply that the GJ is a court, doesn't it?  Also, when you write _GJ will determine if there is enough evidence to_ **convict**, do you mean indict?

Comment: defendants do not defend themselves in front of the GJ, correct?

Comment: @mario Correct, defendants don't appear (except maybe in some special cases). And criminal procedure certainly includes investigations which go nowhere; at a number of law schools, the intro criminal procedure course is entirely about the part between crime and arraignment, with the part from "bail to jail" being taught in the advanced course.

Comment: @cpast i am not sure how to sort out _process_ vs. _procedure_ (vs. _trial_). I am assuming that the first two are not synonymous, since otherwise the expression _procedural due process_ would be awkward (or a pleonasm).

Comment: @mario "Due process" is its own special term; other than when there are special terms that don't mean exactly what you'd think by parsing the constituent words (which is not just a legal thing, but rather is pretty common in English), "procedure" and "process" *are* roughly synonymous. "Procedural due process" is a term precisely *because* "due process" doesn't just talk about the process (it's shorthand for "due process *of law*," and US courts have read into "of law" the notion that something violating the fundamental rights of a free society is no law at all).

Comment: @cpast  again, thanks a lot. I'll think about and maybe ask a new question on translations: _The prosecutor presented evidence at the trial_ :::  _Le procureur a fourni des preuves au procès_